# Throwing $n$ 6-sided dice, what is the probability that the greatest thrown number equals $k=1,...,6$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-coefficients, dice

Let $n$ be the number of 6-sided dice thrown. Further, let $X =$ "Greatest thrown number".

What are the probabilities $P[X=k]$ for every $k=1,...,6$?

Obviously, $P[X=1] = \frac{1}{6^n}$.

I also know that $P[X=k] = P[X\leq k] - P[X\leq k-1]$. Therefore, $P[X=2] = P[X\leq 2] - P[X=1]$.

However, I don't know how to calculate $P[X\leq 2]$ for $n$ dice, although I'm pretty sure it involves the Binomial coefficient?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, what's the probability that a single die comes up $≤2$?

Comment: That would be 2/6 = 1/3

Comment: Ok.  So what's the probability that an event with probability $\frac 13$ occurs $n$ times in a row?

Comment: Oh, I see. The probability for that happening is $(\frac{1}{3})^n$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let n be the number of 6-sided dice thrown and $$k=1,...,6$$. X= "Greatest thrown number".

What are the probabilities $P[X=k]$ for every k=1,...,6?

let us consider the events:

$A_k=${getting a number less than k in the dice}
and $X_i$ the result of $i_{th}$ dice

$$P[X=k]=P[X\leq k]-P[X \leq k-1]$$
$$P[X=k]=P[\bigcap (X_i \leq k)]-P[\bigcap (X_i \leq k-1)]$$
$$P[X=k]=\prod P[(X_i \leq k)]-\prod P[(X_i \leq k-1)]$$

$$P[X=k]=P[A_k]^n-P[A_{k-1}]^n$$

$$P[X=k]=(\frac{k}{6})^n-(\frac{k-1}{6})^n$$